# Spring boot run as java -jar with AJP setting not resolving Web calls via Apache. but API Calls are working

Tags: apache, spring-boot

The Spring boot when running with command Java -jar, only API calls are receiving through Apache, whereas when I hit Hope page URL(or any URL) from the browser, am getting 404.

The following is in APache config (Bitnami server)

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!((server-status|phpmyadmin)([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$))).*$">
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009
</LocationMatch>
```

For AJP, the below  code is added as configuration

```
 @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> servletContainer() {
      return server -> {
        if (server instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
            ((TomcatServletWebServerFactory) server).addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        }
      };
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
       Connector connector = new Connector("AJP/1.3");
       connector.setScheme("http");
       connector.setPort(ajpPort);
       connector.setSecure(false);
       connector.setAllowTrace(false);
       return connector;
    }
```

Am is missing any ProxyPass setting in Apache? or am I missing anything in springboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created war file and ran it as jar, the  code worked.